# How to set date with red highlight on my calender into array not manually

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

Im working on my task now building a calender with php, the problem is my lecture want the date value with red highlight except friday to implement it on array i know if doing it manually with html but with array..? im stuck now ive tried some looping and algorithm but still it not work maybe theres somebody can help me and teach me how to do that

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 background-color: #ecfbff;
 color: #686868;
 }

h2, h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 }

table.calendar { 
 border-left:1px solid #999;
 padding: 0;
 border-spacing: 0;    
 }
td.kotak{
 border: blue solid 2px;  
}
div.day-number-special  { 
 background:red; 
 padding:5px; 
 color:#fff; 
 font-weight:bold;  
 margin:auto; 
 width:20px; 
 text-align:center; 
 }

td.calendar-day { 
 min-height:80px; 
 font-size:11px;  
 } 

td.calendar-day:hover { 
 background:black;
 color:  white; 
 }

td.calendar-day-np {
 background:#eee; 
 min-height:80px; 
 }

td.calendar-day-head { 
 background:aqua; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 text-align:center;  
 padding:5px;
 min-width:57px;  
 border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
 border-top:1px solid #999; 
 border-right:1px solid #999; 
 color: black;
 }

div.day-number { 
 background:#999; 
 padding:5px; 
 color:black; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 position: relative; 
 margin:auto;  
 width:20px; 
 text-align:center; 
 }

td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {  
 padding:5px; 
 border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
 border-right:1px solid #999; 
 }

div.jumat { 
 background:red; 
 padding:5px; 
 color:#fff; 
 font-weight:bold;  
 margin:auto; 
 width:20px; 
 text-align:center; 
 }


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
} 

div.Hari-ini  { 
 background: yellow; 
 padding:5px; 
 color:#fff; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 width: 20px; 
 margin:auto ; 
 text-align:center; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
<head>
 <title>Bima</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>My Calendar</h1>
 <br>
<?php
 function draw_calendar($month,$year){
 
 $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'; 

 $Hari = array('Minggu','Senin','Selasa','Rabu','Kamis','Jumat','Sabtu');
 $Tgl = array('1','5','7','3','19','1','19','30','1','3','4','5','6','7','11','17','1','9','24','25');
 $Bulan = array('1','2','3','4','4','5','5','5','6','6','6','6','6','6','8','8','9','11','12','12');
 $lenth = count($Bulan);
 $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$Hari).'</td></tr>';
 $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
 $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
 $days_in_this_week = 1;
 $day_counter = 0;
 $dates_array = array();

 $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

 for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
  $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
  $days_in_this_week++;
 endfor;
 for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
  $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
  if ($list_day == date('d') && $month == date('m')) {
   $calendar.= '<div class="Hari-ini">'.$list_day.'</div>';
  }
  elseif ( $list_day == 1 && $month == 1 
     || $list_day == 5 && $month == 2 
     || $list_day == 7 && $month == 3 
     || $list_day == 3 && $month == 4
     || $list_day == 19 && $month == 4 
     || $list_day == 1 && $month == 5 
     || $list_day == 19 && $month == 5
     || $list_day == 30 && $month == 5 
     || $list_day == 1 && $month == 6 
     || $list_day == 3 && $month == 6 
     || $list_day == 4 && $month == 6
     || $list_day == 5 && $month == 6 
     || $list_day == 6 && $month == 6
     || $list_day == 7 && $month == 6 
     || $list_day == 11 && $month == 8
     || $list_day == 17 && $month == 8 
     || $list_day == 1 && $month == 9 
     || $list_day == 9 && $month == 11 
     || $list_day == 24 && $month == 12
     || $list_day == 25 && $month == 12) {
   $calendar.= '<div class="day-number-special">'.$list_day.'</div>';
  }
  elseif ($running_day == 5) {
   $calendar.= '<div class="jumat">'.$list_day.'</div>';
  }
  elseif ($running_day != 0 || $running_day != 6) {
   $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';
  }
  $calendar.= '</td>';
  if($running_day == 6):
   if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
   endif;
   $running_day = -1;
   $days_in_this_week = 0;
  endif;
  $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
 endfor;

 if ($days_in_this_week == 1 ): {
   #Sengaja saya kosongkan hanya untuk menghilangkan box berlebih
 }
 elseif($days_in_this_week < 8):
  for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
   $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
  endfor;
 endif;

 $calendar.= '</tr>';

 $calendar.= '</table>';
 
 return $calendar;
 }
 $Hari_Special = array('2019-1-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; New Years Day','2019-2-5 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Chinese New Year','2019-3-7 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Bali Hindu New Year','2019-4-3 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Isra Mi`raj','2019-4-19 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Good Friday','2019-5-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Labour Day','2019-5-19 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Waisak Day','2019-5-30 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Ascension Day of Jesus Christ','2019-6-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Pancasila Day','2019-6-3 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; First Joint holiday before Idul Fitri','2019-6-4 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Second Joint holiday before Idul Fitri','2019-6-5 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Fitri Day 1','2019-6-6 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Fitri Day 2','2019-6-7 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Joint holiday after Idul Fitri','2019-8-11 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Adha','2019-8-17 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Independence Day','2019-9-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Islamic New Year','2019-11-9 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Prophet Muhammad`s Birthday','2019-12-24 &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Christmast Holiday','2019-12-25 &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Christmast Day');
?>  
<?php    
echo '<table>',
  '<tr>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Januari 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(1,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Februari 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(2,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Maret 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(3,2019),
    '</td>
  </tr>',
  '<tr>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>April 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(4,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Mei 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(5,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Juni 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(6,2019),
    '</td>
  </tr>',
  '<tr>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Juli 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(7,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Agustus 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(8,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>September 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(9,2019),
    '</td>
  </tr>',
  '<tr>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Oktober 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(10,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>November 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(11,2019),
    '</td>
    <td class="kotak">','<h2>Desember 2019</h2>',
    draw_calendar(12,2019),
    '</td>
  </tr>',
 '</table>';

echo '<br><h3>National Holidays 2019</h3>','<br>';
echo implode('<br>',$Hari_Special);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your php and css file, see if it makes sense for you? I'm not sure if this helps you with your assignment. I didn't really understand your initial question, but the updated code should help you add a CSS class to the different days and then you can use the css class to assign the colors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
<head>
    <title>Bima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Calendar</h1>
    <br>
<?php
    function draw_calendar($month,$year){

    $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'; 

    $Hari = array('Minggu','Senin','Selasa','Rabu','Kamis','Jumat','Sabtu');
    $Tgl = array('1','5','7','3','19','1','19','30','1','3','4','5','6','7','11','17','1','9','24','25');
    $Bulan = array('1','2','3','4','4','5','5','5','6','6','6','6','6','6','8','8','9','11','12','12');
    $specialDays = [
      '1' => ['1']
      '2' => ['5'],
      '3' => ['7'],
      '4' => ['3', '19'],
      '5' => ['1','19','30'],
      '6' => ['1','3','4','5','6','7'],
      '8' => ['11','17'],
      '9' => ['1'],
      '11' => ['9'],
      '12' => ['24', '25']
    ];
    $lenth = count($Bulan);
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$Hari).'</td></tr>';
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!j-m-Y', $list_day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year);
        $currentDay = strtolower($dateObj->format('D'));

        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        if ($list_day == date('d') && $month == date('m')) {
            $calendar.= '<div class="Hari-ini">'.$list_day.'</div>';
        }
        elseif (array_key_exists($month, $specialDays) && in_array($list_day, $specialDays[$month])) {
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number-special">'.$list_day.'</div>';
        }
        elseif ($running_day == 5) {
            $calendar.= '<div class="jumat day-' . $currentDay . '">'.$list_day.'</div>';
        }
        elseif ($running_day != 0 || $running_day != 6) {

            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number day-' . $currentDay . '">' . $list_day .'</div>';
        }
        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    if ($days_in_this_week == 1 ): {
            #Sengaja saya kosongkan hanya untuk menghilangkan box berlebih
    }
    elseif($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    $calendar.= '</table>';

    return $calendar;
    }
    $Hari_Special = array('2019-1-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; New Years Day','2019-2-5 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Chinese New Year','2019-3-7 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Bali Hindu New Year','2019-4-3 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Isra Mi`raj','2019-4-19 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Good Friday','2019-5-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Labour Day','2019-5-19 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Waisak Day','2019-5-30 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Ascension Day of Jesus Christ','2019-6-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Pancasila Day','2019-6-3 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; First Joint holiday before Idul Fitri','2019-6-4 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Second Joint holiday before Idul Fitri','2019-6-5 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Fitri Day 1','2019-6-6 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Fitri Day 2','2019-6-7 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Joint holiday after Idul Fitri','2019-8-11 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Idul Adha','2019-8-17 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Independence Day','2019-9-1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Islamic New Year','2019-11-9 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Prophet Muhammad`s Birthday','2019-12-24 &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Christmast Holiday','2019-12-25 &nbsp; &nbsp; : &nbsp; Christmast Day');
?>  
<?php       
function draw_calendar_year($year) {    
    $output = '';
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month){
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

        if ($month % 3 === 1) {
            $output .= '<tr>';    
        }
        $output .= '<td class="kotak"><h2>' . $monthName . ' ' .$year. '</h2>' . draw_calendar($month, $year) . '</td>';
        if ($month % 3 === 0) {
            $output .= '</tr>';    
        }
    }
    return '<table>' . $output . '</table>';
}

echo draw_calendar_year(2019);

echo '<br><h3>National Holidays 2019</h3>','<br>';
echo implode('<br>',$Hari_Special);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    background-color: #ecfbff;
    color: #686868;
    }

h2, h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    }

table.calendar { 
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;          
    }
td.kotak{
    border: blue solid 2px;     
}
div.day-number-special  { 
    background:red; 
    padding:5px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold;  
    margin:auto; 
    width:20px; 
    text-align:center; 
    }

td.calendar-day { 
    min-height:80px; 
    font-size:11px;  
    } 

td.calendar-day:hover   { 
    background:black;
    color:  white; 
    }

td.calendar-day-np  {
    background:#eee; 
    min-height:80px; 
    }

td.calendar-day-head { 
    background:aqua; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-align:center;  
    padding:5px;
    min-width:57px;  
    border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
    border-top:1px solid #999; 
    border-right:1px solid #999; 
    color: black;
    }

div.day-number  { 
    background:#999; 
    padding:5px; 
    color:black; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    position: relative; 
    margin:auto;     
    width:20px; 
    text-align:center; 
    }

td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {  
    padding:5px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
    border-right:1px solid #999; 
    }

div.jumat   { 
    background:red; 
    padding:5px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold;  
    margin:auto; 
    width:20px; 
    text-align:center; 
    }


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
} 

div.Hari-ini  { 
    background: yellow; 
    padding:5px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width: 20px; 
    margin:auto ; 
    text-align:center; 
    }

 div.day-mon, 
 div.day-tue, 
 div.day-wed, 
 div.day-thu,
 div.day-sat,
 div.day-sun {
     background: #ff0000;
 } 

 div.day-fri {
     background: #999;
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but that's not what my really question, what i mean is, at this code "elseif ( $list_day == 1 && $month == 1" start from this line was to make important date at my calender turn into red im using elseif condition for this. what im asking is can i use some array to contain my special date then implement it on my code. For example, the little code above works to make the 1 month 1 color red. etc sorry for my bad english, your help was really helped me through my learn

Comment: Ah! Ok, I think I'm slowly understanding what you are trying to achieve. So, I made some further changes to the code. I think it's a fantastic idea to refactor the huge `elseif` block with all the `||` conditions. See if the changes I made makes sense. Next, you should also consider removing `$Tgl` and `$Bulan` since the new `$specialDays` array should already handle all them for you. Let me know if there are further questions.